# Button's Click event is never fired after Validating event of a textbox is triggered

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, validation, errorprovider

I have a custom user control with few elements in it, so it looks like this:

```
UserControl
   Textbox
   Button
   ....
```

Now if I click the button, like I mentioned in the title,  textbox will loose the focus, and its Validating event will fire...But button's click will never fire... I guess this is an usual behaviour...But what is the proper way, to execute button's Click event if validation didn't fail ?

Here is the code I use for validation:

```
 private void txtPassword_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string errorMessage = _uiValidator.ValidatePassword(txtPassword.Text);

            errRegistration.SetError(txtPassword, errorMessage);
        }
```

So errRegistration.SetError() has been executed succesfully - errorMessage is null, means no validation errors, so I guess that is fine (I checked this by putting a breakpoint).

And this is the button's Click event implementation:

```
    private void btnRegisterUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _uiValidator.ValidatePassword(txtUsername.Text);
       //validate other fields here...

        if (_uiValidator.IsValid())
        {
           this._controller.Save();

       }else{
            MessageBox.Show("...", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       }   
    }
```

Comment: Is the text box data bound? What happens if you comment out the `_Validating` handler body? There must be something which is canceling the event (setting `e.Cancel` to `true`)

Comment: Data isn't bound... I populate the textbox's Text value manually. I am pretty much positive that I dont have e.Cancel = true in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnRegisterUser_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        // Set focus on control
        control.Focus();
        // Validate causes the control's Validating event to be fired,
        // if CausesValidation is True
        if (!Validate())
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Try something like that.

Comment: Have you tried entering data that will cause a validation error, if so what was the result?

Comment: Check my updated code, I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish. Windows forms require a lot more validation coding than ASP.NET.

Comment: The thing is, that `btnRegisterUser_Click` is not triggered at all  even if an input is valid. When the input is invalid, I get error provider's icon blinking so, that part is fine...I guess it is some silly error on my side so I will double-check the rest of my code.

Comment: Here, see if this can help you. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/13922/validate-user-input-in-windows-forms